# How do I change the application orientation of a Surface application

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I need to rotate the UI 180 degrees of my surface application in runtime when a user presses a button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform%28VS.95%29.aspx) on your topmost panel (I think you can even do it on the actual surface window if you want) with an angle of 180 degrees.

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="SurfaceApplication1.SurfaceWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
    Title="SurfaceApplication1">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
      <RotateTransform x:Name="mainOrientation"/>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <s:SurfaceButton Click="btn_Click" Content="Click to rotate" />   
    ... other content here ...
   </Grid>
</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void btn_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (mainOrientation.Angle == 0)
        mainOrientation.Angle = 180;
    else
        mainOrientation.Angle = 0;
}
```

As a related topic, you can also listen to the surface's [OrientationChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.applicationlauncher.orientationchanged.aspx) to know when a user has changed side of your app. A good practice is to flip the app to the correct side when this happens.